# AWS S3 concurrent write / overwrite

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I had a look at similar question but it does not answer to my question.

I am looking for is a way to soft lock an update to S3 object.

Multiple users could be viewing and updating an S3 object at the same time (concurrency issue). I would like to put to s3 when the value of Etag I have (when I did a get) is same as the ETag of the object on S3 (conditional update), else reject it (a soft locking), ensuring no one else has made an update before me. Much like database soft locking `update table x set p = q where version = 1;`

Comment: S3 has no such functionality

Comment: Perhaps S3 Object Versioning would suit here. Clients can request the latest version of an object or a specific version (analogous to your ETag approach).